# How to load software onto vx570 terminal using thumb drive?

Tags: verifone

The vx570 has a USB port that I know you can use as a software download vector, but when I tried it, I was unable to initiate the download process.  There is nothing in system mode that would allow me to to execute a program like DDL, which we use for serial (RS232) downloads.  What do I need to do to initiate the download and how do I specify where the files should go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is actually pretty simple.

1) Create a folder for each file group you want to put data in.  So if you want to put something into RAM in file group 3, then name the folder `3`.  If you want to put something into FLASH in file group 3, then name it `F3`.  You can mix at match at will so if you are going to load your program in to file group 3 and it has both RAM and FLASH components, then you would have a `3` folder AND an `F3` folder. If you were also loading VMAC, then you would ALSO have a `1`, `F1`, `15` and `F15`.

2) Package all this stuff up into a `.zip` file.  **You MUST name it `Verifone.zip`**  Put this file onto your USB thumb drive at the root level.

3) Go into system mode and press '#' to start a full download into group 1.

4) Insert the thumb drive into the USB slot on the 570.  The terminal will see that there is a file called `Verifone.zip` and will guide you through the rest.

There is one potentially tricky thing about all of this and that is the config.sys variables.  Since you aren't using `DDL.exe`, you don't have a way to set them during the download.  You **CAN**, however, load the config.sys file directly to the terminal as part of the download.  The problem is that it is a compressed format file, so if you were to look at it in notepad, it would contain a bunch of junk like `äåöíáîæéì`.  The only way I know of to generate this file is to use the "Direct Upload Utility" as found on VeriFone's DevNet site.  As it turns out, it will also do the rest of step 1 (above) for you, as well.

1) Download DUL from DevNet onto your computer

2) Using `DDL.exe` (or whatever you have been using to set up terminals in the past), configure a terminal to be in the exact state that you want your future downloads to be in.

3) Connect the terminal to your computer and run DUL.  Use the * wildcard to specify that you want all files to upload to your computer.  See DUL's documentation for more details.

4) Optional: DUL's naming convention is to prefix RAM folders with `I` and use 2 digit group numbers.  I suspect this will work, but I always change mine to single digits and drop the `I` for RAM groups.